# Text parsing with . and : in ANSI C

Tags: c, string, separator

I have string like this `6.28:12.56:-1:1`, 4 double values separated by `:` and I need to get each double constant and each insert into different variable. What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would usually use [`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) for this (`strtok_r` if you use threads or may have otherwise overlapping parsing sequences).

Comment: Note that `strtok` modifies the string as it parses it, so you should probably copy it into a temporary array.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.dotnetperls.com/split:

> **String.Split()** separates strings. Often strings have delimiter characters in their data. Delimiters include "\r\n" newline sequences and the comma and tab characters. Split handles splitting upon string and character delimiters.

```
string s = "6.28:12.56:-1:1";
    //
    // Split string on ':'.
    // ...
    //
    string[] words = s.Split(':');

    for(int i=0;i < words.length;i++)
{
    string word1=words[0];
        string word2=words[1];
        string word3=words[2];
        string word4=words[3];
}
```

**For ANSI C**

**use sscanf**

```
char st[] = "6.28:12.56:-1:1";
double word1, word2, word3, word4;

int rc = sscanf(st, "%lf:%lf:%lf:%lf", &word1, &word2, &word3, &word4);

/* Check that rc is 4 for success */
```

*sscanf function returns the number of items succesfully read

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I know this function from C++, but ANSI C doesn't have this function... I need to write my own splitting function, that is, why I'm asking for easiest way ;).

Comment: The answer should now be as concise and to the point as possible, I hope.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need. I would upvote you but I have low rep for that :/

Comment: As this question is asking for C and C++ is essentially a different language, you should remove the C++ part of your answer.

Comment: @SajadLfc: Begging for upvotes and accepts is considered poor form. Since the question was about C, the portion of your answer that discusses C++ is irrelevant and should be removed. And your C solution works only if you have a fixed number of fields; it can't parse `"6.28:12.56:-1:1:1.23"` (unless you build the format string dynamically, but that would be overkill).

Comment: Yes, that is true, cant parse that expression, but I need 4 doubles and this will give me 4 doubles. It would be better to have solution for only 4 doubles... If there will be time to modify my code, I try to made it with strtok but first time it wouldnt work for me correctly.